# Capture if a barcode was scanned inside application

Tags: swift, swift3, swift5, cifilter

I am developing an application that creates a barcode using `CIFilter`. The question I have is if there is a way to capture at the app level every time the barcode is scanned? The barcode is a way for the device holder to redeem some sort of discount at different businesses. After it is scanned I would want to hit an API that captures that the barcode was scanned by the device holder. Without having to tie into the business systems. What would be the best approach for this? If there is one.

Just a snippet of how I'm creating these barcodes

```
 func generateBarcode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)

        if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
            return UIImage(ciImage: output)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "every time the barcode is scanned" You can't spy on the user activity. What you can is to create a qrcode with a URL that redirects the user to your app or to a website.

Comment: @LeoDabus please see update

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: most likely not.

The screen that is displaying the barcode has (physically) no way of telling if it's being looked at or scanned. It only *emits* light, it doesn't *receive* any information.

I can only think of two ways of getting that information:

1. Use the sensors of the device, like the front camera, to determine if the screen is being scanned. But this is a very hard task since you have to analyze the video stream for signs of scanning (probably with machine learning of some sort). It would also require that the user gives permission to use the camera just for... some kind of feedback?
2. The scanner needs to somehow communicate with the device through some other means, like a local network or through the internet. This an API of some sort, however.

Maybe it's enough for your use case to just track when the user opened the barcode inside the app, assuming this will most likely only happen when they let it be scanned.